# Is there a way to create Microsoft Word Add-ins that are not task panes?

Tags: ms-word

I have a quick question. I am navigating Microsofts documentation and I can't find anything related to the different types of add-ins you can create or how to configure your add-in using their manifest file.

Essentially what I want to know is can I create an add-in that is strictly a button that will do something when I click it? I don't want the task pane to open up.. I just want the button.

It's probably not the best approach, but I'm curious.

Comment: It really depends on what programming environment, security and installation methods you want to use. You don't even mention which programming language you want to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

different types of add ins are supported by visual studio so i suggest you start with installing Visual Studio community (free).

There's two types of Office add ins: vsto and document add ins. Vsto. I recommend vsto.

[Add in types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-solutions-development-overview-vsto)

[Office development in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-office-development-in-visual-studio)

Then there's Office.Net (desktop)and Office.js (online) platforms.

Microsoft has tutorials for each, just google for them. They usually create a taskpane, but that's just as example.

Here are some links to start with

[Reading material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-client-development)

[Reading material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)

In an addin VS project you can create a ribbon, add a ribbon tab and on it a ribbon button. You can then start with the code behind the button. When you've ploughed through these links then you are on your way and remember: google is your friend but real solutions and insights are best found on stackoverflow.com!

Comment: ahaha thank you ! And yes, stackoverflow.com === 'all your solutions'

Comment: @Boeryepes It's usually better to edit your answer when improving it, instead of creating a second one. I recommend you delete your other answer before it gets downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems your requirements are simple, I'd suggest a simple solution. You can start with a simple macro-enabled document in Word and write the code that does what you want. This macro can display a VBA UserForm for interaction with the user, if you need that. If the macro is so simple that the user only has to run it, then assign it to a Quick Access Toolbar button. That way it's always on-screen to run with a mouse-click.

1. At the right-end of the Quick Access Toolbar, click on the down-pointing arrow and choose **More Commands**.
2. On the left side, change *Choose Command from* to **Macros**.
3. On the right side, change *Customize Quick Access Toolbar* to **For TheNameofTheFile.docm**. This allows others to see the same QAT button when they open the document.
4. Select the macro, then click on the **Add** button. It's copied to the right column.
5. If you'd like to add a different icon, click on the **Modify** button and change the icon and/or macro display name.
6. **OK** out. The icon is added to the right end of the QAT. It also gets a keyboard shortcut: if it's the fifth icon in the QAT, you can run it with Alt + 5.

No extra software required, you can do it all with Word. Then after you learn the ins and outs of VBA, you can save your code as an add-in for distribution. There are simple free utilities like the Office Ribbon Editor that let you modify the ribbon to add a button for your add-in: [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor)